# printing dynamic variables before render

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, preact

I am trying to write a preact script which will display different images depending on the API data fetched. However, the fetchWeatherData() function does not seem to call before the output is rendered, even though I use the function componentWillUpdate().
When I try to print this.state.locate in the render() function before returning the data, the output is always undefined, however I need this variable in order to manipulate the images I want to display.
Thanks for your help.

```
// import preact
import { h, render, Component } from 'preact';
// import stylesheets for ipad & button
import style from './style';
import style_iphone from '../button/style_iphone';
// import jquery for API calls
import $ from 'jquery';
// import the Button component
import Button from '../button';

export default class Iphone extends Component {
//var Iphone = React.createClass({

// a constructor with initial set states
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // temperature state
    this.state.temp = "";



}



componentWillUpdate(){
    this.fetchWeatherData();
}
    // a call to fetch weather data via wunderground
    fetchWeatherData = () => {
        // API URL with a structure of : 
ttp://api.wunderground.com/api/key/feature/q/country-code/city.json
        var url = 
"http://api.wunderground.com/api/mykey/conditions/q/UK/London.json";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success : this.parseResponse,
        error : function(req, err){ console.log('API call failed ' + err); }
    })

}


// the main render method for the iphone component
render() {
    // check if temperature data is fetched, if so add the sign styling to the page

    const tempStyles = this.state.temp ? `${style.temperature} ${style.filled}` : style.temperature;
    document.write(this.state.locate);
    // display all weather data

    return (

        <div class={ style.container }>
            <div class={ style.header }>
                <div class={ style.city }>{ this.state.locate }</div>
                <div class={ style.conditions }>{ this.state.cond }</div>
                <span class={ tempStyles }>{ this.state.temp }</span>
            </div>
            <div class={ style.details }></div>
            <div class= { style_iphone.container }>
                { this.state.display }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

parseResponse = (parsed_json) => {
    var location = parsed_json['current_observation']['display_location']['city'];
    var temp_c = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_c'];
    var conditions = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather'];

    // set states for fields so they could be rendered later on
    this.setState({
        locate: location,
        temp: temp_c,
        cond : conditions
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `componentDidMount()` method. You couldn't call `setState` in `componentWillUpdate()` method. That method is used to:

> Now we’ve committed to updating. “Want me to do anything before I re-render?” our component asks. No, we say. Stop bothering us.

You could find more detail at this link:
https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1